# Reverse interpolate from [-60, -30, -10, 0, 3, 6, 10] scale to 0-1 decimal range?

Tags: javascript, typescript, interpolation, reverse

thanks for solving numerous of my problems. <3

I'm sure someone already solved this, but I don't know how the math needed is called (I've tried reverse interpolation etc., but no success) so I'm posting it like this...

I've interpolated x (a knob's decimal value between 0 and 1) to the scale of [-60, -30, -10, 0, 3, 6, 10].

```
function interpolate (scale: number[], value: number) {
   const count = scale.length - 1
   const low = Math.max(Math.floor(count * value), 0) | 0
   const high = Math.min(Math.ceil(count * value), count) | 0
   return lerp(scale[low], scale[high], rescale(value, [low / count, high / count], [0, 1]))
}


function lerp(start: number, end: number, value: number) {
   return (1 - value) * start + value * end
}


function rescale(value: number, srcRange: [number, number], dstRange: [number, number]) {
   const [dstMin, dstMax] = dstRange;
   const [srcMin, srcMax] = srcRange;

   if (srcMin == srcMax) {
       return dstMin
   }

   const scale = (value - srcMin) / (srcMax - srcMin);
   return scale * (dstMax - dstMin) + dstMin;
}
```

When the value is recalled I need to recalculate the 0-1 range decimal value. How?

I've tried the following, but is not correct...

```
function deinterpolate(scale: number[], value: number): number {
   const scale = values.sort((a, b) => a-b)

   for (let i = 0; i < scale.length - 1; i++) {
       const min = scale[i]
       const max = scale[i + 1]
    
       if (min <= value && value <= max) {
           const result = lerp(min, max, value)
           const offset = i / (scale.length - 1)
           return result + offset
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach is:

```
function deinterpolate(scale: number[], value: number): number {
    const count = scale.length - 1;
    let high = scale.findIndex(n => n > value);
    if (high < 0) return 1;
    if (high === 0) return 0;
    const low = high - 1;
    return lerp(low / count, high / count, 
      rescale(value, [scale[low], scale[high]], [0, 1]));
}
```

The main idea here is to use [the `findIndex()` array method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) to identify the smallest index of the `scale` array whose value is greater than the `value` parameter.  This is then the `high` index, and the one before it is the `low` index.  Of course there are possible edge cases where the value that comes out of `deinterpolate()` isn't the same one that went into `interpolate()`: if the scale array has repeated elements; if the scale array ever decreases; if the value is outside of the scale range.  I assume it's okay to ignore those.

Once we identify `low` and `high` we can essentially run your `lerp()`/`rescale()` in reverse, by switching the roles of `scale[j]` and `j / count`.

We can test it:

```
console.log("start test")
const scale = [-60, -30, -10, 0, 3, 6, 10];
for (let value = 0; value <= 1; value += (1 / 256)) {
    const interped = interpolate(scale, value);
    const deinterped = deinterpolate(scale, interped);
    if (Math.abs(value - deinterped) > 0.00001) {
        console.log("OOPS", value, interped, deinterped)
    }
}
console.log("end test")
// "start test"
// "end test"
```

Since this doesn't print "OOPS", it's a good indication that it works, at least for the example in your question.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=8#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABDMUCmAnADnANgQ3QAoBnCfXNALkTBAFsAjTAbQF0AaRANwpGtoNmGAJSIA3gChEMxBAQkocuOCUBeRGQpoAdJTABzKAAtEAWkQBGabPlhFiXHADuiDQFlCxnfXwAPIk8THWAnOAwieVVEACoePjQRLgAGMQAfRGSbGTsHYxgDUw8vHxRAkog0GFxIlVRY+Nx+JOVVdMzsxAw0KBAMJEpsUnJKFidnTk0RtBZ8wsnurUoiXia0LjGXRAB6VtQuOdNdqNRJlmSuSzYREUkAX0lH0EhYBEdMLFIofAwoGjomJguGgwAATf5CIGNfgQwGiCSdbq9fqIIiWczQxINRQ-JQAakxDRBoPuj0kz2g8CQi2mKwSsOEXBIGAgACV8IYBCwAYzBHDJqDFOzOTRuZCMFweZhrgjZMp7EoWIKoO4UFxlZ4-Gw3IhlcKDGgANydXKK5kQVVgJkszXajTm-VGx5ymDAVHmy1ue02-xiKRyuVIvpIDUoToPE0KJRLNA6ulrDEelBiXakH1+RM25PGwM9YNTbQNIga-wY0NgMQE8vGiMU14hqqoD54QhoYbaBmsSarGF84QiTsYWW2KN7dQFyh6EFGUwWSw52SUJSHHUxkIoUEASTBaACSDUAD5aIgjz3EguZK7USuADyZMRBlHzzpXogrtQf+9dPMo5IX+UOOMOornO-6PgMHxEEBxx1FABwFEcY5cDS2jxvwGwxpsExMtMswIWwZwXFY1wiDWjy5HguhOAYRAAEQ4r8iDoIotG3KaE6xhoLBmAAbERZgAMz8ZYRFEQJXA8ZcyRsMawDhKiS6Ehof6EjeGjzoSeIaGiOyIAATAArDxNzDjko4oOg2BoKCOoWc2BDEDGXBnqRkYKrqjaWVg1k6qCnn2a27aUFwdlWaCrkum65TBPgjAkGhsYWH5oXeeFJ6ZDoyRZcklh+p0coUZO1F0QA8iVAAKADKtHOQkIVNmF6r+WFtxyg8DyFVRcA0bRxJMWgLG3Nsuz0d8jHMVAtGSMNiC9WC-UsZIQA)

Comment: Whoa, that was fast, it works and i understand and appreciate the explanation with the solution. Thanks a lot!